# How to store utf 8 characters and query as it is in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, elk

I want to store all kinds of special characters to field data that should support all types of characters like utf 8 data type does in SQL.

After storing I need to fetch that data while querying the same data as it is

I mean if I index: a+z///d then I should query a+z///d and get this result

Comment: What are your issues? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: You have to provide us the data where you are facing the problem

Comment: I want to store { "Name": "abc" "Source":"asdg shdrjr',asgjjjk/?++&$$$ Hhhjjjj" }

Here in source field I want to store all types of data with secial characters as well

Now when I am querying

"query":{ "query_string":{ "default_field": "source" "query":"asdg shdrjr',asgjjjk/?++&$$$ Hhhjjjj" }}

I should be able to get the result which is present So here I am not sure which tokenizer and analyzer combination shall I use for this requirement.